# NoPermissionsInAccessToken when acessing GraphAPI in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-ad-v2

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API 3, authorization code flow against AzureAD v2 + PKCE.

When I get the acess_token within my controller and then try get a user photo via DelegateAuthenticationProvider, I receive NoPermissionsInAccessToken
Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

Does anyone know ho wit can be fixed?

When I decode the access_token - the scopes are there.

Here is my code.

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
(requestMessage) => {
 requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer",token);
return Task.FromResult(0);});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(graphAPIEndpoint, delegateAuthProvider);

var content = await graphClient .Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Edit - Auth code:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
         options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
         options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
         options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
         options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
         options.ClientSecret = "secret";

         options.UsePkce = true;
         options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;

         options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
         options.Scope.Add("openid");
         options.Scope.Add("email");
         options.Scope.Add("profile");
         options.Scope.Add("user.read");

         var graphAPIScopeAll = "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read";
         options.Scope.Add(graphAPIScopeAll);

         options.SaveTokens = true;      
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you use to get access token?

Comment: @Jim Xu you mean how I do authentication?

Comment: Yea. I want to know  how you do auth.

Comment: Added to the question